# How to export a functional component function?

Tags: reactjs

Given the following functional component, how do I export `someFunction` *without breaking it out into a separate file*, so that I may test it?

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const someFunction = () => {
    ...
    return someValue;
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(someFunction());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Adding an export in front of the function declaration does not seem to work.

Comment: You need to define it in module scope and use `export` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @yury-tarabanko mentioned the `export` keyword can only be used in the module scope, a.k.a. the file root.

```js
export const someFunction = () => {
  ...
  return someValue;
};

export const MyComponent = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(someFunction());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Just do `export default function FunctionName(){ }`

or

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const someFunction = () => {
    ...
    return someValue;
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(someFunction());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mycomponent
```

Comment: this won't do the trick as the function is still only internally accessible